# Is it possible to add or display custom information about the area or MESH you click on a rendered GLTF model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I have a rendered GLTF model using three.js and when you click part of it it highlights that bit red. What I would like to do is when a user clicks that area not only does it highlight it red but it brings up a modal displaying information about that area. My problem is I have no idea how to associate the clicked area with the data. For example if the model was a car and the user clicked the tyre I would like to display some info about that tyre.

What would be the best method for achieving this? Would this custom data be applied to the model when it is built? I don't handle the model itself but can get it altered if needs be I just wasn't sure it worked that way?

When viewing the object for the clicked MESH I can see an empty UserData object which led me down the path of thinking that custom data can be applied to the model itself before being exported.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: I have had to do this before and I exported my model in obj format and named each part of my model. I then had an associated .json file named the same as the obj file to store the information. The json was just an object, keyed by names of the different named parts of the obj.

Comment: Any data in a glTF [`.extras` fields](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#reference-extras) will be available in the resulting three.js objects' `.userData` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Some exporters do allow setting custom 'userData' fields but the most consistently available field is the .name field of a given object/mesh which is usually derived from the name of the object in the modelling software.
.userData is usually just used for storing runtime state in your scene graph in a way that won't interfere with the objects build in properties. .userData will also get serialized with the object during toJSON operations.
I would start by checking what the names of the models components are by doing either scene.traverse or model.traverse( (o)=>console.log(o.name) ) to get an idea of what names are already in the model.